# Repeat Elements in the Pagination

Tags: php, pagination, repeat

```
[...]
$count = count($array_sub);

$per_page = 12;

$numero_pagine = ceil($count / $per_page);

$separator = "?pos=" ;
$page_corrente = (isset($_GET["pos"]) AND intval($_GET["pos"])) ? min($numero_pagine, intval($_GET["pos"])) : 1;

$righi_da_visualizzare = array_slice($array_sub, ($page_corrente-1)*$per_page, $per_page);

/* -- Pagination -- */
$output_pagination = '<nav id="pagination">';
for($i=1; $i<=$numero_pagine; $i++ ) { 
    if($i!=$page_corrente) {
        $output_pagination .= '<a href="' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . $separator . $i . '">' .$i . '</a>';
    }
}
$output_pagination.= "</nav>";
```

The elements in total are 27 and so I have 3 pages;

First page: 12 elements | /page.php?pos=1

Second page: 12 elements | /page.php?pos=2

Third page: 3 elements | /page.php?pos=3

This is correct; but the element that are in the last page (third page) are repeated in the pages (that must not exist)...for exemple:

Fourth page: 3 elements | /page.php?pos=4

Fiveth page: 3 elements | /page.php?pos=5

Etc.

Why there are other ?pos with elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of this line

```
$page_corrente = (isset($_GET["pos"]) AND intval($_GET["pos"])) ? min($numero_pagine, intval($_GET["pos"])) : 1;
```

Here, when your $_GET is higher than three you set it three, so you get the page of three.

Comment: Right. So I try ---> `if($_GET["pos"]>$numero_pagine) {
   header ("location: http://www.site.net/$sec/$sub.php?pos=1"); 
 }` But after ( Here [PAGE](http://www.fantapic.net/adulti18/bikini.php?pos=1) ), when I scroll on down reapt always first page. How can I solve?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you exactly want. The page you showed is not scrollable for me.

Comment: (Try again now)

I want that whan arrive at last page, it stop and don't continue.

Comment: And this code from your first comment does not work? It's ok, you may try to `die()` after the `header()`.